# Sorting an array in O(N) time

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

given an array `A` of the integers `1,2,3,...,N` and the character `" "`(space) 
we want to sort it to be `[1,2,3,...,N," "]`, where we can only swap integers with " ", but not with each other, so `swap(3," ")` is allowed while `swap(1,2)` is not.

My attempt at it was to denote the space be `"-1"`, and search for it in O(N) time, then go over the array again from `i=1` to `N+1` and if I see for example `A[2] = 7`, I would swap `A[7]` with `" "`, then I'd swap `A[2]` with `" "` while keeping track of `" "`'s position since It's the only way to swap, that way `7` would end up at `A[7]` ( with the exception of index shifting)
The code I wrote is the following:

```
public static int[] arraySort(int[] array){

    int space = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++ ){
        if(array[i] == -1){
            space = i;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
        if(array[i] != i+1 && array[i] !=-1){
            swap(array, array[i]-1 , space);
            space = array[i]-1;
            swap(array, i, space);
            space = i;
        }
    }
    return array;
}

public static void swap(int[] arr, int ind1, int ind2){

    int temp = arr[ind2];
    arr[ind2] = arr[ind1];
    arr[ind1] = temp;
}
```

It did work, however for input such as `A[7,3,5,4,6,1,2,-1]`
it failed, I'm aware that I might be sending an integer to the head of the array but I can't see why it wouldn't get back out since a different number goes there then it would eventually go to its position. 
Help? or an idea of how to fix this( while still keeping it in `O(N)` time if possible?

Comment: `"given an array , A , of the integers 1,2,3,...,N"`, this sounds like your array cannot contain negative integers, but then in your test case (`[7,3,5,4,6,1,2,-1]`), you're using a negative integer. Can the input array contain negative integers as well as positive integers, or only positive integers?

Comment: The -1 denotes the space character , it’s not an integer in the array, the array is of size N+1 and contains only 1,2,3,...,N,-1(space)

Comment: How, I’m not allowed to create another array only make swaps with the “ “ . I think it has to be inplace plus some steps in counting sort would be redundant here , like counting the multiplicity of each number in the range since it obviously 1

Answer (score 2):

Using counting sort technique. All the time put the space at the end of the array. You have an array with size N+1. Now, try to read the array from the first place. For example, it is 3. You should put 3 in the 3rd place of the array. To do this, swap the current 3rd value of the array with space, and then swap the first place of the array with the 3rd, and then swap the first with the last item of the array. The latter step will be done to keep the space at the end of the array.

```
public static int[] arraySort(int[] array){
    int N = array.length - 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        int currentNum = array[i]-1;
        swap(array, currentNum, N); // swap currentNum-th item with space as the last memebr of the array
        swap(array, i, currentNum); // swap the current item with its place
        swap(array, i, N); // swap the space with the last item.
    }

    return array;
}

public static void swap(int[] arr, int ind1, int ind2){
    int temp = arr[ind2];
    arr[ind2] = arr[ind1];
    arr[ind1] = temp;
}
```

In the above code, we assume that the location of the space in the start array is in the last. If it is not, you can find it in `O(N)` and swap it with the last place of the array.

Comment: Why do you still declare a `space` variable, when you use `N` as space?

Comment: @Holger Unfortunately, I can't get what you say. You say `swap(array, currentNum, N); `. Now, the space is located in position `currentNum`. So, why we can't `swap(array, i, currentNum);`?

Comment: It depends on the meaning of “space”. Normally, “space” is a location, not a numeric value. You seem to consider that space is the value you’ve move to the location `currentNum`, but contradict yourself then with the comment “`swap the current item with its place`”. Anyway, the actual problem of your code has been described by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57657544/2711488) already. It’s just an additional irritation that you declare a variable `space` that you are not using at all.

Comment: @Holger thanks for extra `space` variable. Anyhow, `swap the current item with its place` is explained by the provided example. I mean swap `3` with the third location which is space at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

#### Step 1 make a lookup array

You make make an array N+1 long, where each value in the lookup array indicates where it is in the array to be sorted. You can make Lookup[0] refer to where the space is. It will take O(n) time to make such an array.
So in the case [7,3,5,4,6,1,2,-1] you make an array [7,5,6,1,3,2,4,0]

### Step 2 move the space to start of the array

you can find the current index of the space by lookup[0], if it is already at index 0, then go to the next step, otherwise swap with index 0.  You should then update the loop array to reflect the change. ie lookup[value that was at 0] = [where the space started].

### Step 3 swap the space with the next element in the array

Now swap the space with `1`. You can find it with the lookup array.

### Step 4 repeat

Now move the space to index 1 if need, and swap with `2`.  Then move the space to index 2 and swap with `3`. Repeat until it is sorted.

Total time is N to make the lookup array, and 2 swaps for each element, total O(3N).

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm you describe is pretty much right, but you made a couple mistakes.

First, you might have to swap multiple times at the same position.  Second, if you hit the space you have to put it in the right place.  Here is your loop fixed.  Note that I stop the iteration one position earlier.

```
for(int i = 0; i<array.length-1; i++){
    while (array[i] != i+1){
        if (space==i) {
            // it's the space
            swap(array, i, array.length-1);
            space = array.length-1;
        } else {
            swap(array, array[i]-1, space);
            space = array[i]-1;
            swap(array, space, i);
            space = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that after we move a number, we always end with `space = i`, so we'll do the space in the next inner iteration.  We can optimize this, ending up with what looks like @OmG's method, except that he missed the while loop too:

```
swap(array, space, array.length-1);

for(int i = 0; i<array.length-1; i++){
    while (array[i] != i+1){
        int currentTarget = array[i]-1;
        //move space to current target
        swap(array, currentTarget, array.length-1);
        //move current element to its target
        swap(array, currentTarget, i);
        //put the space back where it belongs
        swap(array, i, array.length-1);
    }
}
```

It is important to understand why this is still *O(n)*, even though we've added an inner loop:  Each iteration of the inner loop fixes the position of exactly one number, after which we will never move that number again.  This can happen at most *n* times, since there are only that many numbers to fix.

Comment: I’d rather use `swap(array, currentTarget, array.length-1); swap(array, i, array.length-1); swap(array, currentTarget, array.length-1);` to consider “space” to be the location (`array.length-1`) rather than the value, it currently contains. But…is this still `O(n)`?

Comment: @Holger your second swap breaks the OP's rule that you can only swap a number with the space.  If you don't have the rule, then you can just `swap(array, i, currentTarget)`

Comment: As said in my previous comment, I’d consider the *location* `array.length - 1` to be a space, as it simply makes no sense to call a particular numeric value a “space”. But anyway, the question uses a string, which is even more confusing…